# How to remove [xxx more words] text when i sharing post via Jetpack autoposter?

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I already start using Jetpack social auto sharing system for my new posts sending to my facebook and twitter profile timleline.

http://prntscr.com/fh9ffq

But i have a question about this, could we edit sharing template or not ?

Please see this image : http://prntscr.com/fh9fvs

Here is some unwanted words there. For example, i dont want to use, [ 145 more words ] etc. How can i remove this text from my wall posts, is it possible ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you share your website any post link

Comment: sure i updated post ;)